# `mv` creates a hard link instead of move or rename file or directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cygwin, rename, mv

I'm experiencing very weird issue with moving and renaming directories and files using `mv` I have never experienced before. The weirdest thing is that it's happening on *Ubuntu* as well as on *Cygwin* on Windows.

**`mv` attempts to create a hard link instead of actually moving or renaming a file or directory.**

Example of renaming directory:

```
$ mkdir test
$ mv test test2
ln: ‘test’: hard link not allowed for directory
```

Example of renaming file:

```
$ touch test
$ mv test test2
$ ll -i
131140 -rw-rw-r-- 2 user group    0 Nov 13 16:06 test
131140 -rw-rw-r-- 2 user group    0 Nov 13 16:06 test2
```

It's evident that `mv` just created a hard link, because both files have the same inode number.

Why is it doing that?

I have also another system with *Debian* and `mv` is working as I expect there. Is it possible to configure this behavior somewhere in user's dotfiles? If I switch to *root* on *Ubuntu*, `mv` works fine. So I suspect some user's configuration, since I use the same dotfiles for *Linux* as well as for *Cygwin*.

Comment: What is the output of *alias mv*?

Comment: Oh f***. I feel shame. It's an alias of `ln -i`. I have to find out what is doing that alias. Thank you. At least I know where to start.

Comment: OK, solved. It was my fault. When I was creating "secure" aliases for `cp`, `mv` and `ln` with `interactive` argument I copy&pasted previous ones. And I have changed alias content but not alias name in case of `ln` alias. So it was `mv='ln -i'`.

Comment: Always remember the `type` command: it's like `which`, except that it also includes aliases, functions, etc. Like `which`, there is also the `-a` option to show every possible interpretation.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I know it. But I didn't imagine that the cause could be on this level. I suspected something much more low-level, something on system level. Something like "system.filesystem.move_objects_this_way" or so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the cause was purely in me. **I had this alias in my dotfiles which caused that weird behavior: `alias mv='ln -i'`**.

Reason was simple: when I was creating "secured" aliases of `cp`, `mv` and `ln` using the `interactive` argument, I just copy&pasted previous aliases. And in case of an alias `ln`, I have changed content of the alias, but not its name. It should be `ln='ln -i'`, but ended up in previously mentioned `mv='ln -i'`.

I feel shame. Sorry for stupid question, I doubt that someone will ever experience the same issue.